# Duplicate login credential in my user settings under "My Logins"

Tags: bug, login, preferences

I used to have just one login displayed in my account settings. I only have one set of credentials for this account, but now I have two logins displayed in my settings.

[image: two logins showing "Used 6 secs ago"]

I got logged out of my account (I don't think I did anything to log myself out, but I was multitasking, and I suck at multitasking) and now I have two logins, one called "Stack Exchange" and one listed as my email address and each login is showing the exact same timestamp to the second on "last used".

I think what was supposed to happen is that there would be one login and it would be listed as Stack Exchange but something went sideways? I use a gmail.com email, but I don't want to use my actual Google credentials. If it helps, I'm happy to change my email to something else.

I don't think it's anything on my end - I've tried multiple devices and browsers with the same result. I'm reluctant to try to "remove" one of them in case that puts me in a worse situation.

Comment: You can remove credentials yourself

Comment: @Luuklag Obviously, which is why I said “I’m reluctant to remove one of them.” They appear to be identical credentials, so which one is the correct one to remove?

Comment: They actually represent the same credential, and you only have one attached to your account. There's just a weird bug somewhere in the code that sometimes causes the one credential to get displayed as two, which is why the timestamps are the same. Removing one would remove both because they are the same, so please don't try that.

Comment: @animuson That's what I was worried about and why I haven't touched anything :) Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: @animuson might want to consider that as an answer, or tag the question with a status tag?

Comment: @Luuklag It seems like a known hard-to-isolate bug, so I'm OK with leaving this unanswered so that it will maybe pop up again when someone has time to look into it. It's not hurting anything so long as the folks affected don't remove their only credential. I would probably make sure there is a failsafe to prevent people from deleting their only login credentials, but even if I did, I could probably make a new account and ask for it to be merged.

Comment: @ColleenV, yeah I agree that this isn't super top priority to fix, but preserving that information in an anaswer would be best I think. Then the question could be tagged as deferred or by-design, what ever the team sees most fit.

Comment: @Luuklag Tagging as deferred might make sense. I'm not bothered by the info staying in a comment; we all know they aren't as ephemeral as they're claimed to be. The important information is in the question body in terms of helping those with the same problem find it.